# Localizing the zeros of $z^4+z+1$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Consider the complex polynomial $p(z) = z^4+z+1$. I want to check that this polynomial has exactly one zero in each quadrant of $\Bbb C$. I do not want to solve the equation $z^4+z+1 = 0$ (as I strongly believe that's overkill here).

Since the coefficients are real, $z$ being a zero implies that $\overline{z}$ is also a zero. I believe that the strategy is using Rouché's Theorem in some way. So far, I know that all the zeros are in $1/2 < |z|<2$. Trying to use Rouché in, for example, the curve that: joins $0$ to $2$ by a straight segment, then $2$ to $2i$  by a counterclockwise circular arc, and then goes down to $0$ again, seems complicated, as the dominating part of the polynomial can vary.

On the other hand, by the Argument Principle, I could analyze the integral of $p'(z)/p(z)$. But then I would have to tackle the integral: $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{4z^3+1}{z^4+z+1}\,{\rm d}z.$$Maybe I just don't remember my calculus well and this integral is actually easy to deal with, but otherwise I'm  stuck. Can someone give me some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Your integral is very easy,   it's of the form $\frac {du} u$,  so you just get the natural log of the denominator

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Shame on me. At least I was shown a much easier solution `:P`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the sum of the roots is zero. Along with your observation about conjugate pairs, this means that all you need to do is check that the roots are not purely imaginary — which is obvious — or purely real, which follows upon observing that its derivative $4z^3+1$ has only one real zero $-\sqrt[3]{1/4}$, and $$(-\sqrt[3]{1/4})^4-\sqrt[3]{1/4}+1>1-\sqrt[3]{1/4} > 0$$

Comment: Another way to show it can't have real roots: verify $$z^4+z^2+1 = (z^2-1/2)^2 + (z+1/2)^2 + 1/2$$